# iMX31 dependencies?

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-ce, silverlight-embedded

I am beginner in an silverlight application. So at first i looked on demo application which is provided by wince 6.0 r3 at location

> WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\DEMOS\XAMLPERF - **this contains c++ code**
>   and 
>   WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\FILES\XAMLPERF - **this contains xaml file with the images**

Now before running this application in an emulator. I at first proceeded with the following:

1. I have first taken my workspace went to catalog item and added "Silverlight for Windows Embedded"
   from the drop down menu of an catalog item
2. Then right clicked on solution explorer and choosed on properties and under configuration in drop down menu i have selected environment variables where i have added new variable called "sysgen_samplexamlperf" and assigned value as 1 for that variable.
3. Now after rebuiding the application, i have dumped the image into emulator and i found that at desktop of device emulator i can see the exe file to which i run and i can see the application is working fine with 3d effects.

**Now same thing i proceeded in iMX31 hardware and i was not able to see the application running in a proper manner as it was performing in an emulator. So now what i feel is that there be any dependency when we run the application on hardware.**

So what can be the dependency? Also in this location "WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\FILES\XAMLPERF" the images are in png format. So is there any dependency with an image format?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight for Embedded devices does not require HW support. You can add hardware support to enhance performance, but it is not a requirement.

On my PXA3XX platform for example, Silverlight runs without any HW tweaks through the driver.

What is your question exactly? Where is the demo application?
 You can just as well add the XAML based internet explorer to make sure it Silverlight runs. Be aware that the XAML based IE does not have a shortcut on the desktop so you need to create one by yourself or just run the executable from `\Windows`

Comment: You were right. I have not added image encoder and decoder bcz of which the image were not seen at the h/w and i thought that my application was not running. After adding all the neccesary image encoder and decoder from the catalog items, my application was running perfectly well.